# How do i get an ordered list to randomly spit out only some of the list

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list that displays all the questions in a test randomly, but I am trying to have only some of the test display.

I tried making the length of the list shorter and outputting that way but it still dislpays all of the list. Any help is appreciated.

HTML

```
<!-- There are 40 questions but only want 30 to dislpay -->

<ol>
   <li >
      <p id = "question 1">What are the three main areas of the Standard User Interface?</p>
      <ul type="none">
         <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0"  /> Header, Banner, Frame, Application Window</li>
         <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0"  /> Content Frame, Homepage, Form </li>
         <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1"  /> Application Navigator, Banner Frame, Content Frame </li>
         <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0"  /> Larry, Moe, and Curly</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      <p id = "question 2">In the  User interface, what is the gray toolbar called which allows you to add bookmarks?</p>
      <ul type="none">
         <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="0" /> Gauge</li>
         <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="1" /> Edge</li>
         <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="0" /> Remedy</li>
         <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="0" /> Banner</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      <p id = "question 3">What can be captured in an update set?</p>
      <ul type="none">
         <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="0" /> Modified CI Rules</li>
         <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="1" /> Business Rules</li>
         <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="0" /> Scheduled Jobs</li>
         <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="0" /> None of these</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ol>
```

JavaScript

```
// Function that randomizes the test questions that are displayed along 
// with the answers as soon as the page loads

function call_onLoad() {

    var ol = document.querySelector('ol');
    temp = ol.cloneNode(true);

    for (var i = temp.children.length - 10; i >= 0; i--;) {
        temp.appendChild(temp.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);
        alert(temp.children.length);

    }

    ol.parentNode.replaceChild(temp, ol);

    var ul = document.querySelectorAll('ul'),
        parent;
    alert("found " + ul.length + " ul's");

    for (var k = ul.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
        parent = ul[k].parentNode;
        temp = ul[k].cloneNode(true);

        for (var i = temp.children.length + 1; i--;) {
            temp.appendChild(temp.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);

        }

        parent.replaceChild(temp, ul[k]);
    }

}
```

Comment: it is extremely painful to do with plain js, but here's a tip:1. use css and set all display to none. 2. set for loop and run 30 times, check for questions without a class `.display` and add that. 3. use css to set `.display` to show the element.

Comment: also, there cannot be space in a id or class name and no 2 ids can be the same.

Comment: I think you should define your data in javascript, and then generate the HTML.  Or, if you can generate the code on server-side, that may be better

Comment: Not sure what you mean by defining the data in javascript.

Comment: @TheNamesZero like in arrays, e.g. `var quiz = [["question","choice1","choice2","choice3","choice4","answer"],[...],[...]]` Then generate the html according to it.

Comment: so i should assign all 40 questions and 160 choices each to a variable, then put them in an array, and only the display the first 30 questions randomly with appropriate answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to still randomize the questions and only output however much I wanted. I just put if(i>=30){
           temp.removeChild(temp.children[Math.random() * i| 0])
                    }  inside the for loop that was used to append the question list and it works.  Not sure if this is the most optimal way but it works.

```
function call_onLoad() {

var ol = document.querySelector('ol');
temp = ol.cloneNode(true);

for (var i = temp.children.length - 10; i >= 0; i--;) {
    temp.appendChild(temp.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);
    alert(temp.children.length);
       if(i>=30){
            temp.removeChild(temp.children[Math.random() * i| 0])
                }
}

ol.parentNode.replaceChild(temp, ol);

var ul = document.querySelectorAll('ul'),
    parent;
alert("found " + ul.length + " ul's");

for (var k = ul.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
    parent = ul[k].parentNode;
    temp = ul[k].cloneNode(true);

    for (var i = temp.children.length + 1; i--;) {
        temp.appendChild(temp.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);

    }

    parent.replaceChild(temp, ul[k]);
}

}
```